# Transaction in Spring cloud Stream

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream, spring-rabbit

**Problem**: 
I am trying to read a big file line by line and putting the message in a RabbitMQ.
I want to commit to rabbitMQ at the end of the file. If any record in the file is bad, then I want to revoke the messages published to the queue.

**Technologies**:
Spring boot,
Spring cloud stream,
RabbitMQ

Could you please help me in implementing this transition stuff.
I know how to read a file and publish to a queue using spring cloud stream.

**Edit:**

```
  @Transactional
  public void sendToQueue(List<Data> dataList) {

      for(Data data:dataList)
      {
          this.output.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(data).build());
          counter++; // I can see message getting published in the queue though management plugin
      }
      LOGGER.debug("message sent to Q2");

  }
```

**Here is my config:**

```
spring: 
   cloud:    
      stream:
        bindings:
           # Q1 input channel
           tpi_q1_input:
            destination: TPI_Q1
            binder: local_rabbit
            content-type: application/json
            group: TPIService
            # Q2 output channel  
           tpi_q2_output:
            destination: TPI_Q2
            binder: local_rabbit
            content-type: application/json
            group: TPIService
            # Q2 input channel
           tpi_q2_input:
            destination: TPI_Q2
            binder: local_rabbit
            content-type: application/json
            group: TPIService     
        binders:
          local_rabbit:
            type: rabbit
            environment:
              spring:
                rabbitmq:
                  host: localhost
                  port: 5672
                  username: guest
                  password: guest
                  virtual-host: /
          rabbit:
            bindings:
                  tpi_q2_output:
                    producer:
                          #autoBindDlq: true
                          transacted: true
                          #batchingEnabled: true
                  tpi_q2_input:  
                   consumer:
                        acknowledgeMode: AUTO
                        #autoBindDlq: true
                        #recoveryInterval: 5000
                        transacted: true       

spring.cloud.stream.default-binder: local_rabbit
```

**Java config**

```
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class QueueConfig {

  @Bean
  public RabbitTransactionManager transactionManager(ConnectionFactory cf) {
    return new RabbitTransactionManager(cf);
  }
}
```

**Receiver**

```
@StreamListener(JmsQueueConstants.QUEUE_2_INPUT)
  @Transactional
  public void receiveMesssage(Data data) {

    logger.info("Message Received in Q2:");
  }
```

[image: Q2 is the queue getting published in transation]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Configure the producer to use transactions `...producer.transacted=true`
2. Publish the messages within the scope of a transaction (using the RabbitTransactionManager).

Use normal Spring transaction mechanisms for #2 (`@Transacted` annotation or a `TransactionTemplate`).

The transaction will commit if you exit normally, or roll back if you throw an exception.

**EDIT**

Example:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(Source.class)
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class So50372319Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So50372319Application.class, args).close();
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(MessageChannel output, RabbitTemplate template, AmqpAdmin admin,
            TransactionalSender sender) {
        admin.deleteQueue("so50372319.group");
        admin.declareQueue(new Queue("so50372319.group"));
        admin.declareBinding(new Binding("so50372319.group", DestinationType.QUEUE, "output", "#", null));
        return args -> {
            sender.send("foo", "bar");
            System.out.println("Received: " + new String(template.receive("so50372319.group", 10_000).getBody()));
            System.out.println("Received: " + new String(template.receive("so50372319.group", 10_000).getBody()));
            try {
                sender.send("baz", "qux");
            }
            catch (RuntimeException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
            System.out.println("Received: " + template.receive("so50372319.group", 3_000));
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public RabbitTransactionManager transactionManager(ConnectionFactory cf) {
        return new RabbitTransactionManager(cf);
    }

}

@Component
class TransactionalSender {

    private final MessageChannel output;

    public TransactionalSender(MessageChannel output) {
        this.output = output;
    }

    @Transactional
    public void send(String... data) {
        for (String datum : data) {
            this.output.send(new GenericMessage<>(datum));
            if ("qux".equals(datum)) {
                throw new RuntimeException("fail");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

and

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.destination=output
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.output.producer.transacted=true
```

and

```
Received: foo
Received: bar
fail
Received: null
```

Comment: Thanks Gary. I would try this.

Comment: That said, you are asking about "very large file". . . I am actually wondering about your architecture... What does it mean "very large file"? Gb, Tb, etc? Are you planning to populate the queue with that manny uncommitted messages? It would probably be better if you explain your business case. The core issue is that you're mixing transactional and un-transactional systems together into some type of hybrid and IMHO it's never a good thing

Comment: Agreed, if the files are huge, it might be better to write the rows (without a transaction) to a new queue created for each file. Then, when the file is complete send a message with the queue name. If you want to "roll back" for some reason, simply delete the queue.

Comment: I have a file with 10000 records. 
use case is:
1. Read data from a file line by line
2. Keep pushing to the queue.
3. If everything is fine till end , Commit.
4. Read the same queue and start processin g the messages which I have pushed. 

I know it sound's very weird design but I have no control over this.

Comment: @GaryRussell Do you mean to say request response model using queues i.e dynamic queues?

Comment: No; not request/response; I mean publish to a new queue for each file and then send a signal message to the consumer that the queue is ready to be consumed from.

Comment: @GaryRussell The application which is publishing is consuming as well. If there are multiple instances running, how the new queue will be shared with all?

Comment: You would have to fan out the control message to each instance and fire up the consumers dynamically.

Comment: @gary I am following your answer but there is no producer. transacted property present in spring cloud stream.

Comment: What do you mean? See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Elmhurst.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/index.html#_rabbit_producer_properties).

Comment: Sorry. It is there. I did as you told me but the transaction is not working. I loop through the iterator and publishing the individual message to queue but as soon as I publish it got appeared on the queue. I want it should appear after I come out of the iterator without any exception. I have marked all the method with @Transational and producer as transacted: true.

Comment: @GaryRussell Please help. It is quite urgent and I am stuck :(

Comment: @GaryRussell How to use RabbitTransactionManager with spring cloud stream?

Comment: If the `@Transactional` annotation on a method has a reference to it (either explicitly or because it's a bean named `transactionManager` (and `@EnableTransactionManagement` is present on a `@Configuration` class), the transaction will start when the method is entered. Then, all sends from that method on a transactional `RabbitTemplate` (used within the binding) will participate in the transaction. Read the Spring Framework docs about transaction management. Alternatively, use it with a transactional Spring Integration poller. If you still can't figure it out; I'll build an example on Monday.

Comment: @GaryRussell Thanks, Gary. I would try this first thing tomorrow morning. As I don't have the access from home and let you know.

Comment: @GaryRussell For some strange reason, it didn't work :(

Comment: I was very busy today; I will try to find some time tomorrow.

Comment: @GaryRussell Hope to hear from you soon. As I can not find any example online as well

Comment: @GaryRussell Thanks for your time. I will try this. Just for the clarification :

admin.deleteQueue("so50372319.group");
        admin.declareQueue(new Queue("so50372319.group"));
        admin.declareBinding(new Binding("so50372319.group", DestinationType.QUEUE, "output", "#", null));

Above code is just for the demo.  In real spring cloud stream will make the queue by configuration. Am I right?

Comment: Yes; producers don't normally bind queues (unless you add `requiredGroups`).

Comment: @Transactional
  public void sendToQueue(List<Data> dataList) {
    
for(Data data: dataList)
   {
    if(counter==3)
    {
     throw new RuntimeException();
    }
    
    this.output.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(data).build());
    counter++; ------> I can see the message in rabbitMQ management at this line even before this for loop exit normally.
}} why ?

Comment: Don't put code in comments; it's too hard to read. Edit the question instead and show more of your configuration. You must have something incorrectly configured my example works just fine.

Comment: @GaryRussell Added all my changes .please have a look.

Comment: Looks fine on the face of it; I suggest you post the complete project someplace so I can take a look to see what you are doing wrong. As I said, my simple example works fine.

Comment: @GaryRussell It worked after making the Q1 transacted as well from where I am reading the messages and Q2 where I am writing the message after processing.