# RabbitMQ Spring cloud stream Publish message only when database transaction is committed

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream, spring-rabbit

I have this use case where the message has to be published only when the transaction is committed to the database, right now the listener is picking the message before the transaction is committed to the DB and this will result in an exception on listener side... I am retrying processing the message at listener using DLQ, but I want to avoid this problem at first place because I have this problem at multiple places and all the logs are polluted with retry attempts.

I have followed the approach documented here but somehow am not able to make it work [Transaction in Spring cloud Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50372319/transaction-in-spring-cloud-stream) , here RabbitTransactionManager bean is getting created but it's not referred anywhere, not sure how's the wiring happening with rest of the stuff,

This is the code I have tried, can some one please let me know where did I make mistake ?

```java
@Component
@Slf4j
@NoArgsConstructor
public class MQSender {

    public boolean send(MessageChannel messageChannel, AbstractMqMsg abstractMqMsg) {
        return messageChannel.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(abstractMqMsg).build());
    }
}


public interface MetadataMQChannels {
    @Output(QueueConstants.VALIDATE_METADATA_CHANNEL)
    MessageChannel validateMetadataPublishChannel();
}

@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class QueueConstants {
    public static final String VALIDATE_METADATA_CHANNEL = "validateMetadataPublishChannel";
}
```

```
#application-properties 
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.validateMetadataPublishChannel.producer.transacted=true
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.validateMetadataPublishChannel.producer.routingKeyExpression='validatemetadata'
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.validateMetadataErrorPublishChannel.destination=metadata-error-exchange
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.validateMetadataErrorPublishChannel.producer.requiredGroups=validate-metadata-error-queue
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.validateMetadataErrorPublishChannel.producer.exchangeType=direct
```

```java
@Service
@Slf4j
class ValidatePackage{

    @Autowired
    private MQSender mqSender;
    
    @Autowired
    private MetadataMQChannels metadataMQChannels;
    
    @Autowired
    private MetadataService metadataService;
    
    //Publishing the message in the context of transaction 
    @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public MetaDataDto create(MetaDataDto metadata) throws BaseException {
        
        metadataService.saveMetadata(); //persist dto to the Database
        mqSender.send(metadataMQChannels.validateMetadataChannel(), metadata); //publish the message 
    }
}


@SpringBootApplication
@Slf4j
@EnableBinding(value = {MetadataMQChannels.class})
@EnableAsync
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class ManagerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(ManagerApplication.class);
        log.info("Manager Application has been started successfully");
    }
    
    @Bean
    public RabbitTransactionManager transactionManager(ConnectionFactory cf) {
        return new RabbitTransactionManager(cf);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `transacted` rabbit producer binding property so that its `RabbitTemplate` will participate in the transaction

https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit/docs/3.0.10.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit.html#rabbit-prod-props

> **transacted**

> Whether to use transacted channels.

> Default: false.

You seem to have that set to true, so something else must be going on. I suggest setting a breakpoint in `RabbitTemplate.execute` to see what's going on.