# Spring cloud stream : StreamBridge and Transaction

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

I would like to have a spring cloud stream listener handling a fulle transaction regarding all messages sent in it. Or, all message sent manually with StreamBridge in the function are commited even if there is an exception after.

This is my lib versions :

```
spring : 2.5.5
spring cloud stream : 3.1.4
spring cloud stream rabbit binder : 3.1.4
```

My spring cloud stream conf :

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    function:
      definition: test
    stream:
      rabbit:
        default:
          producer:
            transacted: true
          consumer:
            transacted: true
        bindings:
          test-in-0:
            consumer:
              queueNameGroupOnly: true
              receive-timeout: 500
              transacted: true
          test-out-0:
            producer:
              queueNameGroupOnly: true
              transacted: true
          other-out-0:
            producer:
              queueNameGroupOnly: true
              transacted: true
      bindings:
        test-in-0:
          destination: test.request
          group: test.request
          consumer:
            requiredGroups: test.request
            maxAttempts: 1
        test-out-0:
          destination: test.response
          group:  test.response
          producer:
            requiredGroups:  test.response
        other-out-0:
          destination: test.other.request
          group: test.other.request
          producer:
            requiredGroups: test.other.request
```

My test java code :

```java
@Configuration
public class TestSender {
    @Bean
    public Function<Message<TestRequest>, Message<String>> test(Service service) {
        return (request) -> service.run(request.getPayload().getContent());
    }
}
```

```java
@Component
@Transactional
public class Service {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Service.class);
    StreamBridge bridge;
    IWorker worker;
    public Service(StreamBridge bridge, IWorker worker) {
        this.bridge = bridge;
        this.worker = worker;
    }

    @Transactional
    public Message<String> run(String message) {
        LOGGER.info("Processing {}", message);
        bridge.send("other-out-0", MessageBuilder.withPayload("test")
                .setHeader("toto", "titi").build());
        if (message.equals("error")) {
            throw new RuntimeException("test error");
        }
        return MessageBuilder.withPayload("test")
                .setHeader("toto", "titi").build();
    }
}
```

Test class to run :

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class EmptyWorkerApplication {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EmptyWorkerApplication.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EmptyWorkerApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(RabbitTemplate template) {
        return args -> {
            LOGGER.info("Sending messages ...");
template.convertAndSend("test.request", "#",
                                org.springframework.amqp.core.MessageBuilder.withBody(
                                                "{\"content\":\"toto\"}".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
                                        .setContentType("application/json")
                                        .build());
        template.convertAndSend("test.request", "#",
                                org.springframework.amqp.core.MessageBuilder.withBody(
                                        "{\"content\":\"error\"}".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
                                        .setContentType("application/json")
                                        .build());
        template.convertAndSend("test.request", "#",
                                org.springframework.amqp.core.MessageBuilder.withBody(
                                        "{\"content\":\"titi\"}".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
                                        .setContentType("application/json")
                                        .build());
        };
    }
```

I also added a TransactionManager :

```java
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class TransactionManagerConfiguration {

    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    public RabbitTransactionManager rabbitTransactionManager(ConnectionFactory cf) {
        RabbitTransactionManager manager = new RabbitTransactionManager(cf);
        return manager;
    }

}
```

With this example at the end i have in my rabbit queues :

[image: result]

Or i was expected to have only 2 message on test.other.request. What i'm doing wrong ?

**EDIT 1**

Tryed code :

```java
@Component("myfunction")
public class Myfunction implements Consumer<String> {

    private final StreamBridge streamBridge;

    public Myfunction(StreamBridge streamBridge) {
        this.streamBridge = streamBridge;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void accept(String request) {
        this.streamBridge.send("myfunction-out-0", request);
        if (request.equals("error")) {
            throw new RuntimeException("test error");
        }
    }
}
```

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class EmptyWorkerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EmptyWorkerApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public RabbitTransactionManager rabbitTransactionManager(ConnectionFactory cf) {
        RabbitTransactionManager manager = new RabbitTransactionManager(cf);
        return manager;
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(RabbitTemplate template) {
        return args -> {
template.convertAndSend("test.request", "#",
                                org.springframework.amqp.core.MessageBuilder.withBody(
                                                "test".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
                                        .setContentType("text/plain")
                                        .build());
        template.convertAndSend("test.request", "#",
                                org.springframework.amqp.core.MessageBuilder.withBody(
                                        "error".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
                                        .setContentType("text/plain")
                                        .build());
        template.convertAndSend("test.request", "#",
                                org.springframework.amqp.core.MessageBuilder.withBody(
                                        "test".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
                                        .setContentType("text/plain")
                                        .build());
        };
    }
}
```

```yaml
spring:
  rabbitmq:
    host: xx
    port: xx
    username: xx
    password: xx
    virtual-host: xx
  cloud:
    function:
      definition: myfunction
    stream:
      rabbit:
         bindings:
           myfunction-in-0:
             queueNameGroupOnly: true
           myfunction-out-0:
             queueNameGroupOnly: true
             transacted: true
      bindings:
        myfunction-in-0:
          destination: test.request
          group: test.request
          consumer:
            requiredGroups: test.request
            autoBindDlq: true
            maxAttempts: 1
        myfunction-out-0:
          destination: test.response
          group:  test.response
          producer:
            requiredGroups:  test.response
```

**EDIT 2 :**

I finally succeeded to make it work.
My mistake was to set the property
`spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.myfunction-in-0.consumer.transacted=true`
instead of
`spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.myfunction-in.consumer.transacted=true`

I actually dont understand the difference and i didn't found any explanation in both spring cloud stream and spring cloud rabbit binder documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see this answer - [Spring cloud stream : how to use @Transactional with new Consumer<> functional programming model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69698441/spring-cloud-stream-how-to-use-transactional-with-new-consumer-functional-p/69706649?noredirect=1#comment123271252_69706649)
There is also a link to a working example that I just did for a user in comments

Comment: Thanks, i will look to your sample code at https://github.com/olegz/stream-function-samples/tree/main/stream-rabbit-producer-transaction

Comment: I tried to do the same example as yours but i still have all my messages in my output queue even the error ones. The diference is that i use spring-cloud-dependencies 2020.0.4 and not 2020.1.0-SNAPSHOT like you. I updated my question with the example i tryed to copy from yours.

Comment: Ok i succeeded to make it work. Thanki you. I was missunderstanding the <bindingname> in the spring cloud configuration i used name-out-0 instead of name-our in both configuration and use of StreamBridge. Thanks for your support.